# Android: delete blank screen displayed before Splash screen

Tags: android, background, splash-screen

I created a `Splash screen` and it works fine. The only problem is that before the `Activity`with the background image is displayed, for a second, a screen appears with the default theme of Android and the background of the app. What can I do to stop this screen appearing on startup?

thanks

**StartActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

    tareaAsincInicio = new tareaAsincronaInicio();
    tareaAsincInicio.execute();
}
```

**Styles**

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I didn't get your question, please explain in brief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this custom_title_splash_theme to your Splash Activity in manifest

```
<style name="custom_title_splash_theme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

    </style>
```

or simply add this in your style

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Comment: Hope it helps you,all the best :)

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you but please don't forget to vote my friend :)